# Software or Framework for Reverse-Engineering Embedded Systems

Tags: embedded, reverse-engineering

Is there a software platform or program that will allow someone to JTAG or USB connect their embedded board to another computer, and determine all the internal hardware components of the board?

Comment: Nope.  The system on the other end of the USB could easily be set up to pretend to be an entirely different system.  Or it could sit there like a lump and ignore your commands.

Comment: If it were *their" embedded board, why wouldn't they already kow what it was composed of!  It it were someone else's board, its designe is arguably none of your business. Only devices on the JTAG chain could feasibly be detected via JTAG, and I don't think the JTAG standard has a standard method of device identification.  Connecting software kind of has to know what it is looking for to communicate.  Moreover this question is not within the scope of this Q&A site.

Answer (score 0):

As Clifford says, in general it's possible only for the devices on the JTAG scan chain. On many embedded devices only the main CPU has exposed JTAG, so that won't give you much. However, if you do have several chips on the chain, *there is* a tool that allows you to figure out the connections between them. It is called **[jrev](http://nsa.unaligned.org/jrev.php)**. Also, most (I think) JTAG-connected devices generally do implement the IDCODE command, so it should be possible to identify them.